# Json Schema validation for "null" string and empty string

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex for json schema validator which should accept any text except "null" (null string) and empty string. I achieved one of them but not both. Is there any way to combine both?

```
^(?!\\s*$).+

^((?!(NULL)).)*$/i
```

Comment: Try `^(null|\s*?)$`. This will match both null and empty strings.

Comment: Thanks ran, but what I want is to not accept null and spaces. Above regex accepts  both

Comment: Yeah, try the other way `!regex.find()`

Comment: Oh I can't use it as I have only json schema file where I need to write regex as pattern (by the by this is in mule).

Comment: try this `^(?!.*null)(?=.*[^\s]+).*$`  https://regex101.com/r/TKq1Wn/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?![nN][uU][lL]{2}$)\s*\S.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TKq1Wn/5).

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![nN][uU][lL]{2}$)` - the whole string cannot be `null` (case insensitive)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\S` - a single non-whitespace char
- `.*` - any 0+ chars.

Example of usage:

```
{
   "type": "string",
   "pattern": "^(?![nN][uU][lL]{2}$)\\s*\\S.*"
}
```

Also, if the whole string match is not required, use just `"pattern": "^(?![nN][uU][lL]{2}$)\\s*\\S"`.

Comment: That works fine bro with little improvement added.                                                            
 ^(?![n|N][u|U][l|L][l|L]{1}$)\\s*\\S.* works better in my case. Thanks @Wiktor